# Git clone with authentication over HTTP protocol

Tags: linux, git, apache, centos, git-clone

I have a centos 7 server with a git repo shared over smart http, when I make "git push" the authentication works but when I make "git clone" not works. I want than Git and Apache ask me user and password to clone the repos.

/var/www/git -> Is my repo dir
/var/www/html -> Is the web sites dir

My site.conf is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName miserver.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /var/www/git
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /git /usr/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend/

<Directory /var/www/html/gitweb>
    Options +ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/git>
    DAV On
    Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "git repository"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/git/.htpasswd
</Directory>

<Files "git-http-backend">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git Access"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/git/.htpasswd
    Require expr !(%{QUERY_STRING} -strmatch '*service=git-receive-pack*' || %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#/git-receive-pack$#)
    Require valid-user
</Files>

ErrorLog /var/www/html/error.log
CustomLog /var/www/html/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration uses a `Require expr` that matches on `git-receive-pack`.  That's the service that's used when you push to the server.  In order to make the server require authentication for clones and fetches, you need to match on `git-upload-pack` as well.

The easiest way to fix this is probably to remove that `Require expr` line, since it sounds like you want the server to always apply authentication, regardless of the task you're performing.  Removing the `Require expr` lines removes the exemption for non-push operations.